# SetOnClickListener to change view in List Linearlayout

Tags: android, list, view, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

i have created list linearlayout with my code

```
String[] name = {"Chicken", "Beef", "Milk" ,"Juice"};
    final Integer[] price = {10, 50, 5, 3};
    final Integer[] qty = {1, 2, 5, 5};

    listOrder.removeAllViews();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams image = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Utility.getDip(175, CartActivity.this), Utility.getDip(70, CartActivity.this));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams text = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Utility.getDip(140, CartActivity.this), Utility.getDip(80, CartActivity.this));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textQty = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Utility.getDip(100, CartActivity.this), Utility.getDip(80, CartActivity.this));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textPrice = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Utility.getDip(125, CartActivity.this), Utility.getDip(80, CartActivity.this));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textTotal = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Utility.getDip(130, CartActivity.this), Utility.getDip(80, CartActivity.this));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams editImage = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Utility.getDip(40, CartActivity.this), Utility.getDip(40, CartActivity.this));
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        list = new LinearLayout(ctx);
        list.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        //if((i % 2) == 0) list.setBackgroundColor(R.color.bg_grey);

        listImage = new ImageView(ctx);
        //listImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sample_logo_publisher));
        listImage.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_grey));
        listImage.setAdjustViewBounds(Boolean.TRUE);
        listImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        image.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        image.setMargins(Utility.getDip(10, CartActivity.this), 0, Utility.getDip(10, CartActivity.this), 0);
        list.addView(listImage, image);

        listText = new TextView(ctx);
        listText.setText(name[i]);
        listText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        text.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        text.setMargins(Utility.getDip(10, CartActivity.this), 0, 0, 0);
        list.addView(listText, text);

        listQty = new TextView(ctx);
        listQty.setText(qty[i].toString());
        listQty.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textQty.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        textQty.setMargins(Utility.getDip(5, CartActivity.this), 0, Utility.getDip(5, CartActivity.this), 0);
        list.addView(listQty, textQty);

        listPrice = new TextView(ctx);
        listPrice.setText(price[i].toString());
        listPrice.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        textPrice.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        list.addView(listPrice, textPrice);

        Integer total = qty[i]*price[i];
        listTotal = new TextView(ctx);
        listTotal.setText(total.toString());
        listTotal.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        textTotal.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        textTotal.setMargins(Utility.getDip(5, CartActivity.this), 0, Utility.getDip(2, CartActivity.this), 0);
        list.addView(listTotal, textTotal);

        plus = new ImageView(ctx);
        plus.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.plus));
        plus.setAdjustViewBounds(Boolean.TRUE);
        plus.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        editImage.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        list.addView(plus, editImage);
        final int pos = i;
        plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                qty[pos] = qty[pos] + 1;
                listQty.setText(qty[pos].toString());
                listTotal.setText(""+ (qty[pos]*price[pos]));
            }
        });

        minus = new ImageView(ctx);
        minus.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.min));
        minus.setAdjustViewBounds(Boolean.TRUE);
        minus.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        editImage.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        list.addView(minus, editImage);

        remove = new ImageView(ctx);
        remove.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.trash));
        remove.setAdjustViewBounds(Boolean.TRUE);
        remove.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        editImage.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        list.addView(remove, editImage);

        listOrder.addView(list);
    }
```

I want to add quantity when onclick on plus image. But when i clicked plus image in the list, textQty changed in end of the list, not in the same list that I have clicked the image.

how to fix my code?

Comment: I would start separating your logic from your layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have  resolved my problem. Here is my code ... 
I set id in listQty and listTotal

```
listQty = new TextView(ctx);
listQty.setId(99000+i);
listQty.setText(qty[i].toString());
listQty.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
textQty.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
textQty.setMargins(Utility.getDip(5, CartActivity.this), 0, Utility.getDip(5, CartActivity.this), 0);
list.addView(listQty, textQty);

listTotal = new TextView(ctx);
listTotal.setId(98000+i);
listTotal.setText(total.toString());
listTotal.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
textTotal.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
textTotal.setMargins(Utility.getDip(5, CartActivity.this), 0, Utility.getDip(2, CartActivity.this), 0);
list.addView(listTotal, textTotal);
```

and in clicklistener set variable of listQty and listTotal

```
plus = new ImageView(ctx);
plus.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.plus));
plus.setAdjustViewBounds(Boolean.TRUE);
plus.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
editImage.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
list.addView(plus, editImage);
final int pos = i;
plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listQty = (TextView)findViewById(99000+pos);
        listTotal = (TextView)findViewById(98000+pos);
        qty[pos] = qty[pos] + 1;
        listQty.setText(qty[pos].toString());
        listTotal.setText(""+ (qty[pos]*price[pos]));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the TextViews and button together. They don't know they are in the same iteration of the for loop.

You could put each set of buttons and textviews into an array when you go through your loop.

Then in your onClickListener you would for do something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < buttonArray.length; i++){
    if(v == buttonArray[i]){
       // make whatever changes to TextViews at index i
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks anthropomo, but i have solved my problem with my own code.